# How to remotely debug java via HTTP protocol

Tags: java, debugging, kubernetes, remote-debugging, jdwp

My webapp base springboot is deployed in Kubernetes. Because the company restricts the use of NodePort type of service. Is there any way transfer jdwp to http so that remotely debug via http protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Kubernetes port-forward functionality. Please refer the below blog, on how remote debugging of applications is handled on Openshift

https://dzone.com/articles/remote-debugging-of-java-applications-on-openshift